# JQuery mobile - Use transitions without using changePage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, css-transitions

I am using JQM 1.4 and backbone together.

In the beginning of my project, I was using a config file to disable the JQM router and use the backbone one instead, which called the JQM "changePage" method programmatically on hash change.

But I've got too much problems making it work as I want, while all I need from changePage is the CSS3 transition.

The best option I have is to find a way to use jquery mobile transitions (slide, pop, fade...) without using changePage. If I could use those transitions on DIVs, it would be perfect.

Any clue on how to do that ? I know that there are fine libraries like effeckt.css but I think that JQM is the more mobile-cross-browser compatible (correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Animation classes in jQuery Mobile can be found [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/transitions/). To use them, all you need to do is to add *animation class name* e.g. `fade` plus *animation* class, either `in` or `out`.

Moreover, make sure you remove those classes after `animation` ends by listening to `animationend` event.

```
$("element")
    .addClass("in pop")
    .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
    $(this)
        .removeClass("in pop"); /* remove animation classes */
});
```

---

### Update 1

Check browser's Animation/Transition support, the below should return `true`.

```
$.support.cssAnimations
$.support.cssTransitions
$.support.cssTransform3d
```

For example

```
if (!$.support.cssAnimations) {
  /* don't animate */
}
```

---

### Update 2

The default *fallback* transition for browsers that don't support *Transform3d* is `fade`. The below code is updated to reflect this by checking whether current browser supports *Transform3d*.

---

### Details

Let's you want to animate the below divs dynamically `in` or `out`.

```
<!-- buttons for demo -->
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" data-custom="in">Animate-in</a>
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" data-custom="out">Animate-out</a>
<!-- divs -->
<div class="animateDiv" data-transition="pop"></div>
<div class="animateDiv" data-transition="flip"></div>
```

Add `data-transition` attribute to `div` that should be be equal to *animation* class. Also, add `data-custom` or any custom `data` attribute to define in which direction you divs to be animated, whether `in` or `out`.

Then control them with JS.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (e, ui) {
    /* check support */
    var support = $.support.cssTransform3d && $.support.cssTransitions && $.support.cssAnimations ? true : false;

    $(".ui-btn").on("click", function () {
        var direction = $(this).data("custom"); /* in or out */
        $(".animateDiv").each(function () {
            var animation = support ? $(this).data("transition") + " " + direction : "fade " + direction; /* set "fade" if support is false */
            $(this).addClass(animation);
        });
    });

    $(document).on("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", ".out, .in", function (e) {
        var outORin = $(this).hasClass("in") ? "in" : "out",
            animated = support ? $(this).data("transition") : "fade";
        $(this).removeClass(animated);
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/EjaE9/show)** - **[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/EjaE9/)**
>
> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/TDVtT/show/)** - **[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pLxk4/)** (Fallback)
>
> **[Bonus Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/72d9N/)**

Comment: Does this use a JS fallback for non-CSS3-capable browsers ?

Comment: @Rayjax well, you can check whether browser supports `animation`, `transition` and transform` before you do any kind of animation. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you for your nice example, but it fallbacks only to a fade, it does not make the same animation in JS.
I think that jqm.js has the code to fallback any of jqm.css animations if needed. Correct me if I am wrong. But if I call the jqm.css animations like in your example, how would I call those js fallbacks ?

Comment: @Rayjax this is the default in jQM, when browser doesn't support CSS animation, the fallback is "fade". Check [Fallback transition section.](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/transitions/)

Comment: Thank you. One last thing, isn't there any fallback JS library for at least some transitions yet ? If not, this should be an interesting plugin to build IMO

Comment: @ray in this case, you need to create a custom transition/animation that can work on all browsers.

Comment: For slide animations, this should be fairly simple in JS. That's what I need the most
Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: @ray check this post for custom transition http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/custom-page-transitions-part-2/